# What are the matrices that should be saved while chess board camera caliberation

Tags: opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I want to run a camera calibration process for a project. I was able to successfully run the camera caliberation using EMGU CV. After tuning the code line,

```
CameraCalibration.CalibrateCamera(corners_object_list, corners_points_list,Gray_Frame.Size, IC, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CALIB_TYPE.CV_CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL, out EX_Param);'
```

I was able to get the IntrinsicCameraParameters (IC). Now I am not sure which values I should save in a XML file so I can later use these values for calibrating the camera rather than running the process each time. Can anyone help please? Thanks a lot

Comment: from a single cam calibration, you will need the intrinsics, and the camera matrix (AND NEVER TOUCH THE FOCUS AFTER THAT)

Comment: I have parameters called IncintricMatrix and DistortionCoeffs in IC. Are they the values you mean?  I have no parameters called camera matrix

Comment: yes, i got it wrong above(sorry)